# Generate id by groups

Tags: stata, labeling

I have an issue in Stata I can't solve. My data set looks like the first two columns of the following block, and I would like to add the third column, where `newvar` resets itself anytime `id` changes its value It is important for `newvar` to keep the order of the observations, so I cannot sort by group to generate it.

```
|id|group|newvar
|7 |10   |1
|7 |10   |1
|7 |10   |1
|7 |5    |2
|7 |5    |2
|7 |8    |3
```

Comment: Spelling has been Stata for 30 years.... Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you don't mean what you say as your example shows the new variable changing even though `id` does not.

You can always ensure that the current order is taken literally by working with a variable that tracks observation order

```
 gen long obs = _n
```

Then I guess what you want is

```
bysort id (obs) : gen newvar = sum(group != group[_n-1])
```

This is rather a basic question considering the aim of this forum at professional and enthusiast programmers who are expected to have read documentation and show attempts at code. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for what defines a good question here.